# What reason would Visual Studio ASP.NET Development Server start returning HTTP 503 errors?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cassini, asp.net-development-serv

I've been putting together a website for a few weeks, most of the routine has just been creating new web forms with master pages. I've been using the ASP.NET Development Server to view my additions to the project as I've gone along, but today (seemingly out of nowhere) the server has been returning HTTP 503 errors. I tried restarting VS, then restarting workstation, then making sure that "bypass proxy for local addresses" was enabled on my workstation, but to no avail. Has anyone encountered this behavior before or does anyone have suggestions on logs I can review to investigate? Thanks in advance.

Update: When using telnet, the server returns the markup for what looks to be an ASP.NET server page, listing an HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request. Still getting a 503 in Google Chrome and blank pages in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Maybe there is errors in web.config, so cassini can't understand it. Try to publish website and run it with normal IIS

2) Remove file app_offline.htm from root of your project. It's really generate 503 error with cassini

Comment: I published the website to a development server running IIS and it works fine, so I think the web.config may be okay. I even removed the existing web.config and added a new one to no avail.

Comment: I removed the app_offline.htm file from the project and it now works! Amazing, I've been running into several file issues with various HTML and JPEG files, where I've had to remove them from the project, and restore them with different names in order to get them working. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "It's really generate 503 error with cassini"?

Comment: Removal of app_offline.htm also solved this problem for me / I have no idea why this file suddenly appeared in my project but it blocked everything

Answer (score 0):

did u tried enabling debugging in your web application?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, this error is happening prior to that step in the lifecycle, though.

Comment: are you running the vs with administrative privilages? if not then right click the vs shortcut, then select 'run as' and then enter admin account details, click on ok

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that some other application is now configured, say, in IIS, to listen on the same port/vdir combination. It might be a port conflict between two site/servers/applications. I would get [Fiddler tool](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) to look at response headers and see whether you are getting the response from the server you expect.

Comment: I actually didn't even have IIS installed on this workstation. I used Firebug to look at the headers and it was showing 503.