# ASP.net Website works fine when published but returns HTTP error 503 when debugging with VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, visual-studio-2012, iis-6

I've been using VS 2012 for a while now and haven't had many issues with publishing or debugging my site.

But just today I tried publishing my site to a new port on a local server and after that whenever I tried debugging my site using "Local ISS Web Server" or "Visual studio development server" My page would return:

Firefox:

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:59617.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Chromium:

```
This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 503
```

The strange thing is that I can still publish the site to our server or even locally and have it work. It only doesn't work when debugging. I've tried restarting my computer and trying different ports but haven't had any luck.

I even tried modifying my host file like this guy did: http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/03/12/strange-problem-unable-to-connect-to-the-aspnet-webserver-on-localhost/comment-page-1/#comment-73

but still had no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Of course I find the answer right after I post the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6661177/5428728

I had to go to the root of my project folder and delete the app_offline.htm file.

Comment: removing app-offline.htm also saved my issue.